# Integral $\frac{e^{x}}{e^{x-9} + \sqrt{e^{x+4}}}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate $$\int\frac{e^{x}}{e^{x-9} + \sqrt{e^{x+4}}}\mathrm{d}x$$

What I did is $$t=e^{\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$t^2=e^x$$
$$2t\mathrm{dt}=e^x\mathrm{dx}$$

So we get $$\int \frac{2t}{t^2*e^{-9}+\sqrt{t^2*e^4}}\mathrm{dt}=2\int \frac{t}{t^2*e^{-9}+t*e^2}\mathrm{dt}=2\int \frac{1}{(t*e^{-9}+e^2)}\mathrm{dt}$$

How to continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that

> $$
> \int \frac{1}{(at+b)}\mathrm{d}t=\frac1a\log|at+b|+C
> $$

and may apply it here.

Answer (score 3):

$$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{e^x}{e^{x-9}+\sqrt{e^{x+4}}}dx = \int\frac{e^9\cdot e^x}{e^x+e^9\cdot e^2\sqrt{e^x}}dx$$

Now Let $\displaystyle e^x = t^2\;,$ Then $e^x dx = 2tdt$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{e^9\cdot 2t}{t^2+e^{11}t}dt = 2e^9\int\frac{1}{t+k}dt = 2e^9 \ln|t+k|+\mathcal{C}$$

Where  $\displaystyle k=e^{11}\;,$ So we get $$\displaystyle I = 2e^9\ln|\sqrt{e^x}+e^{11}|+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: in $\int\frac{e^9\cdot e^x}{e^x+e^9\cdot e^2\sqrt{e^x}}dx$ where the e^{-9} came from? thanks

Comment: taking L.C.M of denominator

Comment: Sorry did not get it $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{e^x}{e^{x-9}+\sqrt{e^{x+4}}}dx = \int\frac{e^x}{e^x\cdot e^{-9}+ e^2\sqrt{e^x}}dx$ why can I move $e^{-9}$ to the numerator?

Comment: actually it is $\displaystyle \int\frac{e^x}{e^x\cdot e^{-9}+e^2\cdot \sqrt{e^x}}dx$

Comment: Yes, Sorry, now how can we move it to the numerator?

Comment: So we can write it as $\displaystyle \int\frac{e^x}{\frac{e^x}{e^9}+e^2\sqrt{e^x}}dx = \int\frac{e^x\cdot e^9}{e^x+e^{11}\sqrt{e^x}}dx$

Comment: Multiplying the fraction by $1=\frac{e^9}{e^9}$?

Comment: where did the $e^x$ in the numerator go when substitution, never mind it was divided